# Changed Cursor in Silverlight does not persist

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I have some Silverlight applications. I want to change the cursor to an hourglass until a bunch of events occur. I tried this

```
 Cursor = Cursors.Wait
```

It changes it to an hourglass ok, but as soon as I move my mouse it changes back to the default cursor.

How do I get it to persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The me.cursor didn't work for me but I solved it by referring to the grid within the Silverlight xaml that I want the cursor to cover. In my case LayoutRoot.Cursor = cursor.wait.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Set cursor 
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

     Thread.Sleep(2000);
        // Execute your time-intensive hashing code here...

        // Set cursor as hand 
   this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand ;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't ready want to put the thread to sleep. I am waiting for some asynchronous processes to finish.

Comment: This seems to work, but since I am writing in VB I use Me instead.

Comment: This didn't work for me after all. See my solution posted below.